# custom UITableViewCell subclass not able to get properties assigned

Tags: uitableview

I am trying to build my image picker through the ALAssets library and I have a table view with the albums but when i click on the album to view the photos, in a dynamic UITableViewController composed of custom UITableViewCells it doesnt allow me to assign properties to my custom AlbumContentTableViewCells...

Both cell.rowNumber & indexPath.row are NSIntegers but its complaining about an unrecognized selector...

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

AlbumContentsTableViewCell *cell = [[AlbumContentsTableViewCell alloc] init];

cell = (AlbumContentsTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Photo"];

cell.rowNumber = indexPath.row;
cell.selectionDelegate = self;

// Configure the cell...
NSUInteger firstPhotoInCell = indexPath.row * 4;
NSUInteger lastPhotoInCell  = firstPhotoInCell + 4;

if (assets.count <= firstPhotoInCell) {
    NSLog(@"We are out of range, asking to start with photo %d but we only have %d", firstPhotoInCell, assets.count);
    return nil;
}

NSUInteger currentPhotoIndex = 0;
NSUInteger lastPhotoIndex = MIN(lastPhotoInCell, assets.count);
for ( ; firstPhotoInCell + currentPhotoIndex < lastPhotoIndex ; currentPhotoIndex++) {

    ALAsset *asset = [assets objectAtIndex:firstPhotoInCell + currentPhotoIndex];
    CGImageRef thumbnailImageRef = [asset thumbnail];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumbnailImageRef];

    switch (currentPhotoIndex) {
        case 0:
            [cell photo1].image = thumbnail;
            break;
        case 1:
            [cell photo2].image = thumbnail;
            break;
        case 2:
            [cell photo3].image = thumbnail;
            break;
        case 3:
            [cell photo4].image = thumbnail;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

return cell;
```

}

I get this error when I try to assign this custom UITableCell its 'rowNumber' property:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell
>   setRowNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e2a43a0'

AlbumContentsTableViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "ThumbnailImageView.h"

@class AlbumContentsTableViewCell;

@protocol AlbumContentsTableViewCellSelectionDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)albumContentsTableViewCell:(AlbumContentsTableViewCell *)cell selectedPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

@interface AlbumContentsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <ThumbnailImageViewSelectionDelegate> {

IBOutlet ThumbnailImageView *photo1;
IBOutlet ThumbnailImageView *photo2;
IBOutlet ThumbnailImageView *photo3;
IBOutlet ThumbnailImageView *photo4;

NSInteger rowNumber;
//id <AlbumContentsTableViewCellSelectionDelegate> selectionDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger rowNumber;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<AlbumContentsTableViewCellSelectionDelegate> selectionDelegate;

- (UIImageView *)photo1;
- (UIImageView *)photo2;
- (UIImageView *)photo3;
- (UIImageView *)photo4;

- (void)clearSelection;
@end
```

AlbumContentsTableViewCell.m

```
#import "AlbumContentsTableViewCell.h"
#import "ThumbnailImageView.h"

@implementation AlbumContentsTableViewCell

@synthesize rowNumber;
@synthesize selectionDelegate;
```

[image: story board]

[image: story board]

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ThumbnailImageView;

@protocol ThumbnailImageViewSelectionDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)thumbnailImageViewWasSelected:(ThumbnailImageView *)thumbnailImageView;
@end

@interface ThumbnailImageView : UIImageView {

UIImageView *highlightView;
id <ThumbnailImageViewSelectionDelegate> delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<ThumbnailImageViewSelectionDelegate> delegate;

- (void)clearSelection;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you are calling

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Photo"];
```

It is dequeuing a UITableViewCell and not an AlbumContentsTableViewCell. Since UITableViewCell does not have a setRowNumber: selector it is throwing an exception. You need to be allocating and initing your AlbumContentsTableViewCells somewhere.

**EDIT:**
You need to register your AlbumContentsTableViewCell for use with your @"Photo" identifier. Try adding this to your `viewDidLoad' method:

```
    [self.tableView registerClass:[AlbumContentsTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Photo"];
```

Note that I haven't tested this code out, but I think it is close to what you need.

Comment: just tried that but it didnt work...
 AlbumContentsTableViewCell *cell = [[AlbumContentsTableViewCell alloc] init];
    
    cell = (AlbumContentsTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Photo"];

Comment: Do you mind adding the complete `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to the question?

Comment: That worked! 
however now I cant associate the images from the album with the Thumbnail image views that make up the albumContentsTableViewCell... in the story board they have the appropriate class but not sure if they 'belong' to the table view cell itself... how do i establish this relationship?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm headed off-line for now, sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Have you made the property of your thumbnailimageview in your custom cell to access it, like this 
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ThumbnailImageView *thumbImageView;
Please also check this...